# IEEE 754 as a mathematical space

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

Integer operations in computers (i.e. 32-bit integers) probably can be represented best by modular arithmetic (because of integer overflows/underflows).

What about [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating point arithmetic? You have rounding and negative zeros. What would be the a space(?) in mathematics that comes very near  to numerical floating points?

Comment: My beginner's intuition says that this might be close to a subgroup or subring (not sure if that's a thing) of the rational numbers.  Yet, I'm not sure about the effect of the two $0$'s...

Comment: You will have trouble when taking into account $\pm\infty$s, and of course, the good old, $\mathrm{NaN}$.

Comment: Because of rounding and catastrophic losses of precision, the IEEE operations are not associative. This rules out most of the better-known algebraic structures.

Comment: You may find it interesting that the C standard specifies two types of integers, "signed" and "unsigned".  Unsigned integer arithmetic is defined to be the same as arithmetic mod $2^k$ where $k$ is the word size, and overflow conditions never occur.  But signed integer arithmetic is defined differently, and overflow conditions *do* occur, leading to what is called "undefined behavior".  Underflow in integer arithmetic is impossible by definition.